# Javascript div fade based on position

Tags: javascript, function, loops, position

I want to click a div and have it and other divs fade out one after the other.  I want the time between one div fading and the next div fading to be proportional to the distance between the divs.

All these divs are children of a larger div.

I have code that works to fade the divs.  I am now trying to write a function that will, look at each pixel for the width of the parent div and fade any divs when it comes across them.

Here is the javascript:

```
function sweep(){
    var n3_position = #note_3.position();
    for (i=0;i<900;i++){
        if n3_position.left == i {
            fade('note_3');
        }
    }
}
function fade(el){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(el).fadeOut("slow",function(){
            document.getElmentById(el).style.display="none";
        }); 
    }, 100);
}
```

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<a onclick="sweep()"><div id="note_1"></div></a>
```

So, clicking the first note (the divs are musical notes) should cause the third note to fade once the for loop variable i is equal to the x-position of the left side of the third note.  Ultimately sweep() would create variables for all the div positions and check for each of them, but for now, for testing, it is just this one.  The parent div is 900px wide, so that is the reason for the upper limit of the for loop.

What happens right now is nothing.

All help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance for your expert help.

-Oijl

Comment: there is some issues with your code. At first you call `fade('note_3')` but inside the fade function you have `$(el)` which won't work because it is missing the id selector `#`.

Answer (score 0):

I think have some errors in your first function.  Try something like below and see if that works better for you.

```
function sweep(){
    var n3_position = document.getElementById('note_3').offsetLeft;
    for (i=0;i<900;i++){
        if (n3_position == i) {
            fade('note_3');
        }
    }
}
```

You were missing parenthesis around your if condition in the loop.  Also, #note_3 does not return the element, as such it is not valid.

Additionally there are a few errors in the second function.  Here is something that should work to get you started:

```
function fade(el){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#' + el).fadeOut("slow");
    }, 100);
}
```

You were missing the '#' which you will need since you are referencing the element by Id.  Additionally, you probably don't need to change the display style to none since the fadeOut method is taking care of that for you.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually ended up using a simpler solution, but you helped me with some syntax.